# How to ignore some of the fields in json for comparison in Karate test

Tags: karate

I am new to Karate test firstly.  I am trying to use Karate to test an api endpoint and check the output json message versus a hardcoded json string.  However, one of the field value in the json string is random generated.  So I don't want Karate to compare that field but other fields.  The following is the example.

e.g. Given url 'http:....../api/endpoint'
And method get
and status 200
* def result = response

```
 And match result == { "refNum": "ABC123456", "status": "Stage 1", "expired": "2021-09-19" }
```

As the refNum is a generated field, and I don't want Karate to compare this field.   So how to tell Karate don't compare this field only?

Comment: why don't you read the docs ? the very first "hello world" example shows how to use `#notnull`: https://github.com/intuit/karate#hello-world